# D3: Issue with updated time domain on zoom

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming, pan

I have been experimenting with D3 for some time now, but i have come to a dead end.
On initialization i am creating an svg with the axes set on some default data.

```
Graph.initiateGraph = function(data){

    Graph.time_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
    Graph.time_scale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(Graph.time_extent)
        .range([Graph.padding, Graph.w]);

    Graph.value_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseInt(d.value); });
    Graph.value_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(Graph.value_extent)
        .range([Graph.h, Graph.padding]);

    Graph.svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", Graph.w + Graph.padding)
        .attr("height", Graph.h + Graph.padding)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(Graph.time_scale).y(Graph.value_scale).on("zoom", Graph.zoom));

    Graph.chart = Graph.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","chart")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    Graph.line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){ return Graph.time_scale(d.date); })
        .y(function(d){ return Graph.value_scale(d.value); })
        .interpolate("linear");

    Graph.time_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(Graph.time_scale)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    Graph.value_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(Graph.value_scale)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    Graph.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + Graph.h + ")")
        .call(Graph.time_axis);

    Graph.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","y axis")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + Graph.padding + ",0)")
        .call(Graph.value_axis);

}
```

Then, i have a pair of input boxes that implement jquery calendar script to provide 2 dates (start and end). I then update my svg chart with these dates.

```
$("#date_filter_button").click(function(){

    var start_date = $("#analysis [name='date_start']").datepicker('getDate');
    var end_date = $("#analysis [name='date_end']").datepicker('getDate');

    Graph.time_extent = [start_date.getTime(),end_date.getTime()];
    Graph.time_scale.domain(Graph.time_extent);

    Graph.svg.select(".x.axis").transition().call(Graph.time_axis);
}
```

Unit here everything works like a charm. The x axis domain changes to the dates provided. So then i draw the chart and it works beautifully.

The problem comes when i try to pan/zoom the chart. On the first pan/zoom, the time axis changes to the first default values i used on the initialization.

```
Graph.zoom = function(){

    var trans = d3.event.translate[0],
        scale = d3.event.scale;

    Graph.svg.select(".x.axis").call(Graph.time_axis);
    Graph.svg.select(".y.axis").call(Graph.value_axis);

}
```

It's like when the zoom function comes in and calls the Graph.time-axis, it uses the initial values of the Graph.time_extent and/or Graph.time_scale values...

Comment: Could you provide a live example, preferably on something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: So i managed to solve the problem. The plot is this: you initialize a chart without data (both value axis and time axis). Also you have added a zoom function on the chart to pan/zoom it. User inputs 2 dates so you redraw the time axis according to the values provided and you draw the chart. You also need to recall that zoom function on the svg with the new time values in order to update the zoom function with the correct values.